# elemMatch not returning multiple rows

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to return all promotions nested inside items in array y 3rd level nested, but I am only getting 1 result. What am I doing wrong?

This is the query:

```
db.fulFillmentCenter.find({ _id: 1 },
                 { exclusiveProducts: { $elemMatch: { _id: { $gt: 10} }} })
```

This is the result:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "exclusiveProducts" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(1585857727679),
            "upc" : "p1",
            "totalStock" : 10,
            "availableStock" : 10,
            "price" : 0.0,
            "origin" : "debe aparece",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2020-02-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2020-04-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "active" : true,
            "promotion" : {
                "_id" : NumberLong(1585857727707),
                "promotionId" : "promo1",
                "description" : "string",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "active" : true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and this is my document

/* 1 */

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "_class" : "com.walmart.labsmx.exclusiveproducts.model.FulFillmentCenter",
    "minDateDelivery" : 9,
    "maxDateDelivery" : 2,
    "deliveryCost" : 10.0,
    "origin" : "string",
    "active" : true,
    "exclusiveProducts" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(1585857727679),
            "upc" : "p1",
            "totalStock" : 10,
            "availableStock" : 10,
            "price" : 0.0,
            "origin" : "debe aparece",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2020-02-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2020-04-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "active" : true,
            "promotion" : {
                "_id" : NumberLong(1585857727707),
                "promotionId" : "promo1",
                "description" : "string",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "active" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(1585857727767),
            "upc" : "p2",
            "totalStock" : 10,
            "availableStock" : 10,
            "price" : 0.0,
            "origin" : "no debe aparece",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2020-02-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2020-04-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "active" : false,
            "promotion" : {
                "_id" : NumberLong(1585857727733),
                "promotionId" : "promo1",
                "description" : "string",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "active" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(1585857727683),
            "upc" : "p3",
            "totalStock" : 10,
            "availableStock" : 10,
            "price" : 0.0,
            "origin" : "no debe aparece",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2020-02-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2020-03-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "active" : true,
            "promotion" : {
                "_id" : NumberLong(1585857727764),
                "promotionId" : "promo1",
                "description" : "string",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "active" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(1585857727710),
            "upc" : "p4",
            "totalStock" : 10,
            "availableStock" : 10,
            "price" : 0.0,
            "origin" : "debe aparece",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2020-02-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2020-05-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "active" : true,
            "promotion" : {
                "_id" : NumberLong(1585857727751),
                "promotionId" : "promo1",
                "description" : "string",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "active" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(1585857727710),
            "upc" : "p5",
            "totalStock" : 10,
            "availableStock" : 10,
            "price" : 0.0,
            "origin" : "no debe aparece",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2020-05-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2020-07-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "active" : true,
            "promotion" : {
                "_id" : NumberLong(1585857727716),
                "promotionId" : "promo1",
                "description" : "string",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "active" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(1585857727704),
            "upc" : "p20",
            "totalStock" : 10,
            "availableStock" : 10,
            "price" : 0.0,
            "origin" : "no debe aparece",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2020-05-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2020-07-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "active" : true,
            "promotion" : {
                "_id" : NumberLong(1585857727734),
                "promotionId" : "promo2",
                "description" : "string",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "active" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(1585857727706),
            "upc" : "p21",
            "totalStock" : 10,
            "availableStock" : 10,
            "price" : 0.0,
            "origin" : "no debe aparece",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2020-05-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2020-07-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "active" : true,
            "promotion" : {
                "_id" : NumberLong(1585857727704),
                "promotionId" : "promo3",
                "description" : "string",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "active" : true
            }
        }
    ],
    "exclusiveStores" : [ 
        {
            "storeId" : 123,
            "origin" : "string"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you use elemmatch as a projection operator. As described in the [official doc,](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch), it projects only the first element that match condition.

If you want to project multiple elements, you have to use aggreggation framework to achieve this.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      exclusiveProducts: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$exclusiveProducts",
          as: "product",
          cond: {
            $gt: [
              "$$product._id",
              1585857727700
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

you can try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RM-J4JP6KyV)